# c++ socket connect not working when not using ip

Tags: c++, sockets, dns, connect

I am trying to connect to my Java server with my C++ client through a dns.

So when I type the dns name instead of my localip, It won't connect. Code:
**NOT WORK**

```
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("blalblalb.no-ip.com");
    addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
```

But when I type the ip-address of the dns, it works. Code:
**WORKS**

```
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("174.554.xx.xxx");
    addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
```

Why is that?

Comment: 'NOT WORK' isn't a problem description. You need to provide the `errno`, `perror()` result, etc.

Comment: @EJP Hi, I'm sorry. I wasn't thinking about that since I never got an error message. Luckily someone understood anyway but I will have that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`inet_addr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr)** is supposed to take an address in numbers-and-dots notation only.

If you want to use a hostname, use **[`getaddrinfo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)** instead.  The link to the manual page has a linux example (and [here a Windows example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

*Please note that `inet_addr()` only handles IPv4 adresses and is not compatible with IPv6 format.  You could consider [`inet_ptron()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_pton) for a more future proof development.*

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get the ip address of the server in order to connect to it using `inet_addr()`, you can use `gethostbyname()` in order to achieve this instead.

Edit:
    nvm `gethostbyname()` is deprecated so use `getaddrinfo()`.